# Context path conditions

Tags: commerce, nodes, theming

I am using Context with Delta and Omega3. I am trying to make the Drupal Commerce Checkout, Review and Complete pages each appear differently.  These are their default paths:

```
checkout/*
checkout/*/review
checkout/*/complete
```

The problem is that if you set a condition path to 'checkout/*' in one context then the 'review' and 'complete' condition paths will both be overridden by it.

Is there a way to get separate contexts for each of the 3 pages?

Comment: Drupal's recognition is greedy. Sometimes it's good to define shortest path last. I don't know enough about stuff you are using, not enough to post full answer, but hope that'll help.

Comment: I need to define 3 different contexts for each of the different paths.  Since each condition path is in a different context and there is no way of weighting contexts, I don't think the order of path definition would make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create 3 different contexts, in each context add path condition and set the paths as follow:

**First Context:**

```
checkout/*
~checkout/*/review
~checkout/*/complete
```

**Second Context:**

```
~checkout/*
checkout/*/review
~checkout/*/complete
```

**Third Context:**

```
~checkout/*
~checkout/*/review
checkout/*/complete
```

According to Context documentation **~** character (tilde) can be used to exclude one or more paths.

Comment: That worked.  Despite the module's popularity, I was not able to find much in the way of documentation for Context.  The drupal.org page points to README.txt.  Anyway, I was getting ready to write a plugin so thank you!

Comment: @kalidasan glad my answer helped you :)